# Bluetooth mouse keeps disconnecting

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I am running 17.04 with 4.10.0-38-generic kernel.

My MX Master 2S connected with USBBT2EDR4 (StarTech) keeps coming and going with connectivity, here's a sample of dmesg showing the cycle of a few disconnections and reconnections:

```
[ 1441.324052] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 1441.324064] Bluetooth: Inquiry failed: status 0x1f
[ 1448.140086] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x2005 tx timeout
[ 1449.182541] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 1449.556089] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 1449.698553] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0a5c, idProduct=21e8
[ 1449.698556] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1449.698558] usb 3-1: Product: BCM20702A0
[ 1449.698560] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
[ 1449.698561] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 00190E195555
[ 1449.813550] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[ 1449.829537] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
[ 1449.830536] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[ 1449.830549] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd failed with error -2
[ 1449.830551] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd not found
[ 1449.970495] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
[ 1450.963771] input: MX Master 2S as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B019.0010/input/input22
[ 1450.964499] hid-generic 0005:046D:B019.0010: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v0.03 Keyboard [MX Master 2S] on 00:19:0E:19:55:55
[ 1457.452133] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 1457.452146] Bluetooth: Inquiry failed: status 0x1f
[ 1465.132181] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x2005 tx timeout
[ 1465.309928] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 1465.684176] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 1465.826659] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0a5c, idProduct=21e8
[ 1465.826662] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1465.826664] usb 3-1: Product: BCM20702A0
[ 1465.826666] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
[ 1465.826667] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 00190E195555
[ 1465.937885] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[ 1465.953893] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
[ 1465.954866] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[ 1465.954880] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd failed with error -2
[ 1465.954882] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd not found
[ 1466.096880] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
[ 1467.091357] input: MX Master 2S as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B019.0011/input/input23
[ 1467.092190] hid-generic 0005:046D:B019.0011: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v0.03 Keyboard [MX Master 2S] on 00:19:0E:19:55:55
[ 1905.455944] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 1905.455951] Bluetooth: Inquiry failed: status 0x1f
[ 1913.136032] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x2005 tx timeout
[ 1913.313226] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 9
[ 1913.688046] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 1913.834275] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0a5c, idProduct=21e8
[ 1913.834277] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1913.834279] usb 3-1: Product: BCM20702A0
[ 1913.834279] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
[ 1913.834280] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 00190E195555
[ 1913.950225] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[ 1913.966254] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
[ 1913.967237] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[ 1913.967254] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd failed with error -2
[ 1913.967255] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd not found
[ 1914.107231] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
[ 1914.117239] Bluetooth: hci0 advertising data length corrected
[ 1915.139439] input: MX Master 2S as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:046D:B019.0012/input/input24
[ 1915.139593] hid-generic 0005:046D:B019.0012: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v0.03 Keyboard [MX Master 2S] on 00:19:0E:19:55:55
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Installing bluez-hid2hci fixed this issue for me.

I came across this thread in searching for a similar issue on a Thinkpad Yoga 11e with any bluetooth mice I tried using stock Gnome. Mouse would work, freeze for a few seconds, and usually start working again (sometimes they would just die until a reboot). Installed a bunch of different bt-managers and still got the errors below in journalctl:

```
Jun 14 10:01:17 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 117 using xhci_hcd
Jun 14 10:01:17 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jun 14 10:01:17 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jun 14 10:01:17 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 118 using xhci_hcd
Jun 14 10:01:17 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jun 14 10:01:18 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jun 14 10:01:18 <computername> kernel: usb usb1-port2: attempt power cycle
Jun 14 10:01:18 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 119 using xhci_hcd
Jun 14 10:01:18 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Jun 14 10:01:19 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Jun 14 10:01:19 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: device not accepting address 119, error -71
Jun 14 10:01:19 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 120 using xhci_hcd
Jun 14 10:01:19 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Jun 14 10:01:19 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Jun 14 10:01:19 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: device not accepting address 120, error -71
Jun 14 10:01:19 <computername> kernel: usb usb1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
Jun 14 10:01:34 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 121 using xhci_hcd
Jun 14 10:01:34 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jun 14 10:01:34 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jun 14 10:01:35 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 122 using xhci_hcd
Jun 14 10:01:35 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jun 14 10:01:35 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jun 14 10:01:35 <computername> kernel: usb usb1-port2: attempt power cycle
Jun 14 10:01:36 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 123 using xhci_hcd
Jun 14 10:01:36 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Jun 14 10:01:36 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Jun 14 10:01:36 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: device not accepting address 123, error -71
Jun 14 10:01:36 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 124 using xhci_hcd
Jun 14 10:01:36 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Jun 14 10:01:36 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
Jun 14 10:01:37 <computername> kernel: usb 1-2: device not accepting address 124, error -71
Jun 14 10:01:37 <computername> kernel: usb usb1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Turning the mouse off stopped the messages, so pretty sure it was the culprit of the repeated messages.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `blueman`
2. Run `blueman-manager`
3. Setup your bluetooth mouse as you regularly would
4. *Most important part* : Click on **Trust Device**.

Comment: thx, marking it as trusted fixed it for me